# Including System Libraries with Bjam for Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost-python, bjam

This is probably a really basic question but I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere. I'm building a Python extension in C++ using Boost.Python and need to link my project with libpcap, but nothing I specify seems to point bjam to the correct location. Pcap is currently installed to */usr/local/include* (OS X 10.9) and I can import it with XCode, Make, or any other build system. However when I try to run bjam it gives me the linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64."

I got past the first round of linker errors by adding the other source files to the python-extension definition but obviously can't do the same for an external library. Here's my bjam file (copied from their example and slightly modified):

```
import python ;

if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    ECHO "notice: no Python configured in user-config.jam" ;
    ECHO "notice: will use default configuration" ;
    using python ;
}

use-project boost : ../../../Downloads/boost_1_55_0 ;

# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the
# boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
# /boost/python.
project
  : requirements 
          <library>/boost/python//boost_python 
          <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  : usage-requirements <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  ;

python-extension pcap_ext : PacketWarrior/pcap_ext.cc PacketWarrior/PacketEngine.h PacketWarrior/PacketEngine.cc PacketWarrior/Packet.h ;

# Put the extension and Boost.Python DLL in the current directory, so
# that running script by hand works.
install convenient_copy 
  : pcap_ext
  : <install-dependencies>on <install-type>SHARED_LIB <install-type>PYTHON_EXTENSION 
    <location>. 
  ;

# A little "rule" (function) to clean up the syntax of declaring tests
# of these extension modules.
local rule run-test ( test-name : sources + )
{
    import testing ;
    testing.make-test run-pyd : $(sources) : : $(test-name) ;
}

# Declare test targets
run-test pcap : pcap_ext pcap.py ;
```

I'm sure it's just adding something to the project requirements, but the syntax eludes me and none of the variations of `<libary>` I could find from [0] seemed to work. I tried looking for equivalents of passing the *llibpcap* flag to GCC but to no avail. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

[0] - https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/BuildingExtensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was trying to link to the header paths when it needed the dynamic library. I added this to the requirements rule and bjam was able to compile it correctly.

```
<library>/usr/lib/libpcap.dylib
```