# Writing a python wrapper for C++ program using boost.python?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I want to write a wrapper for C++ code. My ultimate goal is to access classes and their functions written in C++ using python but right now, I am just trying to write a simple wrapper for hello world program. 
So, I looked online and saw boost.python is able to perform such feat. [Their tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/hello.html)  though is not so clear. I am trying to follow it but I am getting lost. Also the tutorial is based on windows systems and i am using mac, so it is creating more confusion for me.
I installed boost and bjam through homebrew.

```
brew install boost --with-python
brew install bjam
```

the code i am trying to wrap.

```
#include <iostream>
char const* greet(){
    return "hello world!"
}
```

Can you help me how to proceed with this?

For now, I downloaded [`Jammroot`script](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/example/tutorial/Jamroot) as directed in tutorial and edited the `use-project boost`to the current location of `boost`(`/usr/local/Cellar/boost`)
then, when i try to run bjam from terminal, i get following error

```
Jamroot:17: in modules.load
*** argument error
* rule use-project ( id : where )
* called with: ( boost : /usr/local/Cellar/boost; project boost-python-    quickstart : requirements <library>/boost/python//boost_python     <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers : usage-    requirements <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers )
* extra argument project
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:1138:see definition of rule 'use-project' being called
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:311: in load-jamfile
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/build-system.jam:535: in load
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/kernel/modules.jam:289: in import
/usr/local/share/boost-build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/usr/local/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam:8: in module scope
```

Comment: i never used boost but you can use something called ctypes. [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python) has a complete example. Good luck

Comment: @Saraiva hey thanks for pointing out ctypes but it seems ctypes is a lengthy process as I have quite elaborate classes to work with. I was hoping if i could figure out boost.python, I can do the warping easily.

Comment: i see. Anyway, tipically in a wrapper you only expose a well-defined interface. Thats how ctypes work and how (for instance) JNI works (i recently had to create a Java wrapper for a c++ code). No matter how complex the existing code is remember that a wrapper accesses the wrapped code through simple well-defined calls (thus the ctypes). Good luck with the boost, i'm sure you will make it work

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322027/including-system-libraries-with-bjam-for-boost-python) it looks like it might help

Comment: Hey thanks for the links. but sadly the boost.python tutorial is still out of my head and not yet working. i am killing myself over it now -.-